# How does one connect Raspberry Pi 4B to mac using arch linux vnc?

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, vnc, tigervnc

I installed TigerVNC in an attempt to connect with a macbook but could not get past a `No matching security types` error. What can I do to connect? I can connect using `tigervnc` to a Windows 7 server with no authentication but apple doesn't offer anything but vnc authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out one just needs to install the following packages, configure the connections, and it works. I can now use just Remmina to configure three different computers with one app. Before I was using `rdesktop` and `tigervnc` apps to get to two different computers. Great app solution.

```
sudo pacman -S libvncserver
sudo pacman -S remmina
```